# Unable to use Enter-PSSession with PowerShell Remote Endpoint

Tags: windows, powershell

I am following this guide to configure, register and then Enter the restricted PowerShell Remote Endpoint - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/01/build-constrained-powershell-endpoint-using-startup-script/

I am following the documentation as it is but I am getting the following error when trying to enter the PSSession -

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $env:Computername -ConfigurationName ConstrainedSession -Verbose
Enter-PSSession : Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "The expression after '&' in a pipeline element 
produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object."
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $env:Computername -ConfigurationName Co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enter-PSSession], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I am registering this startup script while using `Register-PSSession` - http://pasted.co/6b152e12

The registration of the new session also goes through and once registered, I can see the session in `Get-PSSessionConfiguration`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                 
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1715                                                                                        
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                               
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                               
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.1715                                                                                       
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                   
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                   
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? Using Windows Server 2016.